# How to calculate number of picks of cards?

Tags: probability, average, card-games, law-of-large-numbers

There are 4 cards with numbers 3,5,9,2 on each card. You draw card repeatedly one by one until you get card with number 2 on it (every time you put back pulled card),then game stops.
How to calculate the average number of picks?
Is that a law of large numbers or something like that?

Comment: This is a textbook example of a geometric distribution.  A geometric distribution with parameter $p$ (*$p$ representing the probability each independent trial of a "success" occurring*) is **well known** to have expected number $\frac{1}{p}$, in your case here $\frac{1}{1/4} = 4$.  Read any textbook covering an introduction to probability to learn why.

Comment: You're new so you might profit from the following.  First, pare your question to its *essentials*.  The numbers $3,5,9,2$ are ARBITRARY and will confuse readers.  Why *those* numbers?  Instead use $1,2,3,4$ or $A,B,C,D$.  Next always show YOUR work.